# How to filter categories in Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filter

I want to filter by categories in a Webshop. Actually I stuck with a tutorial from Mosh because I have no Error Message in Browser or Command Prompt but nothing is filtered or even showed. I am a absolute beginner in Angular and/or typescript so pls be kind^^ I tried to resolve the problem by my own for ages but it doesn´t work. Please help me out.

Thats my code:

**products.component.ts:**

```
export class ProductsComponent {

 products: Product[]= [];
 filteredProducts: Product[] = [];
categories$: Observable<any>;
category: string;
products$: Observable<any>;


 constructor(
    route: ActivatedRoute,
    productService: ProductService, 
    categoryService: CategoryService) {
    this.filteredProducts;

productService.getAll().subscribe (products => this.products);



//Shows Categories in View
    this.categories$ = categoryService.getAll();
    route.queryParamMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.category = params.get('category');
      this.categories$.subscribe(res => console.log (res)); //Console.log  5 Categories Observable



      //Setting the filtered Products Array
      this.filteredProducts = (this.category) ? 
       this.products.filter(p => {
         return p.category === this.category;
       }) : 
      this.products;
      console.log(this.filteredProducts); // Console.log FilteredProducts Array
    });

   }

 }
```

**products.component.html:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="list-group">


      <!-- Bei queryParams c.name auswählbare Kategorien / bei c.key nicht sowie bei c.$key nicht-->
      <a *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async "
      routerLink= "/"
      [queryParams]="{ category: c.name }"  
       class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
       [class.active]="category === c.name">
        {{ c.name }}
      </a>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="col-9">
    <div class="row">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let product of filteredProducts ; let i = index">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card" style="width: 15rem;">
          <img [src]="product.imageUrl" class="card-img-top" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.title }}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{ product.price | currency: 'EUR' }}</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="(i + 1) % 2 === 0" class="w-100"></div>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: In the Blue bordered box the items of the clicked category should appear]

Comment: Is this.category set correctly? Have you console log it?

Comment: I console loged this.category and it shows the correct clicked category. Did u mean that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `productService.getAll()` method will take some time to fetch data from API, but `route.queryParamMap` will get executed immediately, while this observable is subscribed `this.products` object will be empty, that's why it is not able to filter. also you have not initialized `this.products = products`, in subscription.
To fix all this you can implement it as below :

```
    export class ProductsComponent {

     products: Product[]= [];
     filteredProducts: Product[] = [];
    categories$: Observable<any>;
    category: string;
    products$: Observable<any>;


     constructor(
        route: ActivatedRoute,
        productService: ProductService, 
        categoryService: CategoryService) {
        this.filteredProducts = [];


        //Shows Categories in View
        this.categories$ = categoryService.getAll();
        route.queryParamMap.subscribe(params => {
          this.category = params.get('category');
            });


    productService.getAll().subscribe (products => {
                   this.products = products;
                             //Setting the filtered Products Array
                   this.filteredProducts = (this.category) ? 
                   this.products.filter(p => {
                      return p.category === this.category;
                   }) : this.products;
                   console.log(this.filteredProducts); // Console.log FilteredProducts Array
}); 
       }

     }
```

This is what I get if i console.log as follows: 
productService.getAll().subscribe (products => { console.log(products); this.products = products;});

[image]
and in the CMD:

[image]

Comment: Thank you but I got an error by initialize this.products = products. The error message is :   
Type '{ $key: string; $value: unknown; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Product[]'.
  Type '{ $key: string; $value: unknown; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Product': title, price, category, imageUrlts(2322)

Comment: @FloOmega can you show what response  `productService.getAll()` method gives, there is a type difference.

Comment: This would be the response: (method) ProductService.getAll(): Observable<{
    $key: string;
    $value: unknown;
}[]>

Comment: @FloOmega, from where you will get `products` ?, you have used `this.products` array, but from which service are you getting this is not mentioned, is it in `$value` object ?

Comment: I thought I get products from through the interface Product as an Array. this is my getAll() in the product.service.ts:                                                               
   getAll(){
  return this.db.list('products')
  .snapshotChanges()
  .pipe(map(changes => changes.map(c=>({
    $key: c.payload.key, $value: c.payload.val()
  }))));
}                     and thats my interface: export interface Product{
    title: string
    price: number;
    category: string;
    imageUrl:string;
}

Comment: As I mentioned I am a total beginner and just tried to learn angular with the Tutorial. But it doesnt work the way the teacher tought.

Comment: @FloOmega, please add `console.log(products)`  before `this.products=products` in `productService.getAll()` subscription and show me what it prints on console.

Comment: I had to add console.log(this.products) before  productService.getAll().subscribe( products => this.products); In the console I get a empty Array. If I type just product in the console.log it shows me following: Cannot find name 'products'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.products'?ts(2663)

Comment: @FloOmega not before `productService.getAll()`, inside productServie.getAll().subscribe as : productService.getAll().subscribe (products => {
                   console.log(products); this.products = products;});

Comment: It is not possible to do so. I´m getting this in the Console:  ERROR in src/app/products/products.component.ts:35:74 - error TS2322: Type '{ $key: string; $value: unknown; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Product[]'.
      Type '{ $key: string; $value: unknown; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Product': title, price, category, imageUrl

    35  productService.getAll().subscribe (products => { console.log(products); this.products = products;});

Comment: but in the browser the console.log gives me all products as objects

Comment: Can you show me the screenshot or statements what it prints  ?

Comment: @FloOmega , which db are you using ? is it a mongodb ? or any other, you first have map the data as a product list, there should not be a structure like {$key: string, $value: any}

Comment: Also please add your screenshot in question, instead of separate answer

Comment: Im using Firebase. So an NoSQL DB too. Sorry but I have no clue. I just did it like the teacher but it doesn´t work. The only step which doesnt work is to initialize this productService.getAll().subscribe (products => this.products); to productService.getAll().subscribe (products => this.products = products); But it doesn´t work because the IDE shows me the error I told you.

Comment: In `product.service.ts` getAll() method, instead of using `snapshotChanges()`, you can use `valueChanges()` method, which will directly give you an object list, so replace it with as `getAll(){ return this.db.list<Product>('products') .valueChanges(); } `

Comment: `valueChanges()` will not give you `key`, but if you required a key then you can use it as `this.db.list<Product>('products').snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(changes => 
        changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }))
      )
    );`  Here inside Product object you have to add one property key

Comment: Refer this for more details https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md

Answer (score 0):

well, there're some mistakes, the first is that you has

```
productService.getAll().subscribe (products => this.products);
```

must be

```
productService.getAll().subscribe (products => this.products=products);
```

But this not work becouse is an async call.

So, first change your productService "caching" the products. Your service like

```
products:any[]
getAll()
{
    return products?of(product):
           this.httpClient.get("your-url").pipe(
              tap(res=>this.products=res;
           )
}
```

We use *of* from 'rxjs' and **tap** from 'rxjs/operators'

This make that getProducts return an Observable of products. The first time is called, "products" are undefinned, so return the response of the httpClient.get. The tap make that procuts get the value, so the second time is called the variable products are used.

The second error is used the "constructor" use ngOnInit to subscribe to route.queryParamMap.

```
ngOnInit()
{
   this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.category = params.get('category');

      //here you get all the products
      this.productService.getAll().subscribe (
         products => this.products=products);
         //Setting the filtered Products Array
         this.filteredProducts = (this.category) ? 
             this.products.filter(p => {
              return p.category === this.category;
         }) : 
         this.products;
         console.log(this.filteredProducts); // Console.log FilteredProducts Array
      });
}
```

Well, another aproach is using switchMap and make that filteredProducts becomes an observable (then we use filteredProduct$ | async)

```
   this.filteredProduct$=this.route.queryParamMap.pipe(
     switchMap(params=>{
       this.category=params.get('category');
       return this.productService.getAll().pipe( 
          switchMap(products=>{
              const filteredProduct=!this.category?products:
                   products.filter(p => {
                      return p.category === this.category;
                    }) : 
             return of(filteredProduct):

          })
       )
     })
   )
```

NOTE: I don't check the code but this is the idea, I hope this can be usefull

Answer (score 0):

The problem exist in filtering part, when you gonna filter your products on the base of category, then actually, it did not filter. The reason is that because your program did not get category of product in **p.category**. Because you are using latest angular as well as latest firebase. So you should use **p.payload.val().category**. Then it will compare your category with the **this.category**.

**Try the given code**

```
productService.getAll().pipe(switchMap(products => {
    this.products = products;
    return route.queryParamMap;
  }))
      .subscribe(params => {
      this.category = params.get('category');
      this.filterProducts = (this.category) ?
      this.products.filter(p => (p.payload.val().category)===this.category) :
      this.products;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is simple >_< I lost my 2 hours for solve.
When we give queryParams by c.key - its value is like "bread" - with small letters, but our
product.category value is with uppercase like "Bread" and so u must give value of category name - not category key
Just change

THIS:

```
<a *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" 
    routerLink="/"
    [queryParams]="{ category: c.key }"
    class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
    [class.active] = 'category === c.key'
    >
    {{ c.payload.val().name }}
</a>
```

TO:

```
<a *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" 
    routerLink="/"
    [queryParams]="{ category: c.payload.val().name }"
    class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
    [class.active] = 'category === c.payload.val().name'
    >
    {{ c.payload.val().name }}
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

the correcte anser for the last version of angular is

**products.component.ts:**

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Product } from './../models/product';
import { Categorie } from './../models/categorie';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ProductService } from './../product.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoryService } from '../category.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-products',
  templateUrl: './products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products.component.css']
})
export class ProductsComponent {

products: Product[]= [];
filteredProducts: Product[] = [];
categories$: Observable<any>;
category: string;
products$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(
    route:ActivatedRoute,
    productService:ProductService, 
    categoryService:CategoryService) {
   productService
   .getAll().pipe(
   switchMap(products=>{
     this.products = products;
     return route.queryParamMap;
   }))
   .subscribe(params =>{
     this.category =params.get('category');
     this.filteredProducts =(this.category)?
     this.products.filter(p=>p.category === this.category):
     this.products;
   });`enter code here`
this.categories$ = categoryService.getAll();

     }

    }
```